# Bind header and content dynamically to expander

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp, expander

Firstly I see the type for Header and content for the expander, it says the type is object. I have a user control with name CommonExpanderUserControl as follows,

xaml:

```
<uwpControls:Expander Header="{Binding HeaderContent}" Content="{Binding MainContent}">

</uwpControls:Expander>
```

In xaml.cs (DataContext is set to this)

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderContentProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderContent", typeof(object), typeof(CommonExpanderUserControl), new
         PropertyMetadata(null));

        public object HeaderContent
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(HeaderContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HeaderContentProperty, value); }
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty MainContentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MainContent", typeof(ContentControl), typeof(CommonExpanderUserControl), new
       PropertyMetadata(null));

        public ContentControl MainContent
        {
            get { return (ContentControl)GetValue(MainContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MainContentProperty, value); }
        }
```

Now I am using this UserControl somewhere outside as follows,

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<ContentControl x:Key="Header">
                <Grid x:Name="ExpanderHeaderGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0" Margin="0" 
                      Background="{Binding LisSharedSettings.ChangeHeaderColor,Converter={StaticResource BoolToSolidBrushConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockLisSharedSettingsTitle" 
                                   x:Uid="/Application.GlobalizationLibrary/Resources/InstrumentSettingsViewLisSettingsTextBlockTitle"
                                   Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyleSectionHeader}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ContentControl>

<ContentControl x:Key="Body">
Some content here.
</ContentControl>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
            <local:CommonExpanderUserControl HeaderContent="{StaticResource Header}" MainContent="{StaticResource Body}"/>
</Grid>
```

Binding Content control like that simply doesn't work. If I remove the MainContent binding and bind only the Header, it says object reference not set to an instance of an object. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs [`StaticResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/staticresource-markup-extension) binding, we could not bind header with control by `StaticResource`. And for the scenario the better way is bind `HeaderTemplate` and send the data source to the header property like the following.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
        <Grid
            x:Name="ExpanderHeaderGrid"
            Margin="0"
            Padding="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Background="Red"
            >
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockLisSharedSettingsTitle" Text="{Binding}" />

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <uwpControls:Expander Header="hello" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}" />
</Grid>
```